# paypal masspay allways returning success, even with inexisting users

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm currently testing my paypal integration. When using Masspay, every user name that I enter who hace a mail-like format(an @ and a ".") I get a "success" response. I'm using the following code:

```
def emails =[]
def amounts = []

emails[0]=params.cuenta;
amounts[0]=params.cantidad;



//masspay.massPayCode("Dinero recibido de TikCode.com", "info@tikcode.com", emails,          amount, "EUR");

String emailSub = "Dinero recibido de TikCode.com";
String emailAddress = "info@tikcode.com";
String [] receiverEmailItems = emails;
String [] amountItems = amounts;
String currencyCode = "EUR";
CallerServices caller = new CallerServices();

String responseValue = null;


    APIProfile profile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile();
    /*
     WARNING: Do not embed plaintext credentials in your application code.
     Doing so is insecure and against best practices.
     Your API credentials must be handled securely. Please consider
     encrypting them for use in any production environment, and ensure
     that only authorized individuals may view or modify them.
     */

// Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
    profile.setAPIUsername("myusername");
    profile.setAPIPassword("mypasswordapi");
    //profile.setSignature("AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31ARykt6evANuQsOANN9TjehZjqIl3"); 
    profile.setSignature("mysignature");
    profile.setEnvironment("sandbox");
    caller.setAPIProfile(profile);
    MassPayRequestType pprequest = new MassPayRequestType();
    pprequest.setVersion("90.0");
    println("llegas aqui?")
// Add request-specific fields to the request.
    MassPayRequestItemType[] massPayItem = new MassPayRequestItemType[receiverEmailItems.length];
    int j = 0
    for(int i=0;i<receiverEmailItems.length; i++)
    {
        String recreceiverEmail=receiverEmailItems[i];
        if(recreceiverEmail != null && recreceiverEmail.length()!= 0)
        {
            MassPayRequestItemType massItemReq = new MassPayRequestItemType();
            massItemReq.setReceiverEmail(receiverEmailItems[i]);
            BasicAmountType amount = new BasicAmountType();
               amount.set_value(amountItems[i]);
            amount.setCurrencyID(CurrencyCodeType.fromString(currencyCode));
            //massItemReq.setUniqueId(uniqueIdItems[i]);
            //massItemReq.setNote(noteItems[i]);
            massItemReq.setAmount(amount);
            massPayItem[j]=massItemReq;
            j++;
        }
    }
    pprequest.setEmailSubject(emailSub);
//  pprequest.setReceiverType(ReceiverInfoCodeType.fromString("abdel@publidirecta.com"));
    pprequest.setMassPayItem(massPayItem);

// Execute the API operation and obtain the response.
    MassPayResponseType ppresponse = (MassPayResponseType) caller.call("MassPay", pprequest);
    responseValue = ppresponse.getAck().toString();
```

//  println(ex)
    //  ex.printStackTrace();

```
return responseValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's as intended; MassPay allows money to be transferred to non-registered users.
These people will then receive an email from PayPal, letting them know that money is waiting for them, and they'll just need to sign up to PayPal and confirm their email address to receive it.

The money will then be available to be withdrawn to a bank account, or spent as PayPal balance.